# Programming a Custom Ease

Tags: actionscript-3

Trying to create a dynamic wheelSpin with an easeInOut effect, but I want to manipulate the strength of the in and out more precisely. It will have a much longer ease out for example. AS3 Tween locks you into some simple presets but doesn't give me the control I need. I haven't found any tutorials on how to make one. The only thing I've seen for this is Greensock Custom Ease, but I'm trying to either create my own or use something free that doesn't have license of use issues first.

I have an idea to create a movie clip where I tween a simple object using bezier control, then making a call to the tweened property each frame and store it in a variable. Then I make a function for the object I want to manipulate to apply this change over a time relevant to that movies length of time. It seems like a functional hack...but rather clunky. I'd rather keep this code driven.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my tweening class [ru.delimiter.math.TweenALot](https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/2756fadd741a6d44276fde1701470daf24cebfa8/classes/ru/delimiter/math/TweenAlot.as?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), it depends on **ru.delimiter.events.Chronos** from the same repo, you can grab it or you can change **TweenALot** to use **ENTER_FRAME** instead.

The class is pretty old so please don't judge me for its style.

The usage:

```
import ru.delimiter.math.TweenALot;

var aTween:TweenALot = new TweenALot;

// The tweening target.
aTween.target = this;

// The destination properties.
aTween.properties = {x:100, y:100, alpha:0};

// The tweening duration, in milliseconds.
aTween.duration = 3000;

// Easing.
aTween.easingFunction = TweenALot.easeInOut;

// Pass the complete handler and start tweening.
aTween.start(onComplete);

function onComplete():void
{
    trace("I have disappeared!");

    // Destroy and release the tween instance.
    aTween.destroy();
    aTween = null;
}
```

Then, at the bottom of the class, there are a number of easing functions, I believe I did them to be compatible with something, just don't remember what exactly. Thus, you can create your own easing functions, you don't even need to add them to the class, just assign them to **easingFunction** property of the tween.

```
function weirdEasing(t:Number, b:Number, c:Number, d:Number):Number
{
    var aProgress:Number = Math.min(1, t / d);

    if (aProgress <= 0.5) return b;

    return b + c * Math.pow((aProgress - 0.5) * 2, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative nice tween to give a slow organic tween out effect, slower than most exponential tweens, is using plain and simple zeno's paradox:

```
obj.x += (targetX - obj.x) / 0.5;
```

Just play with parameters, or add finer control. It's fun. You can add a check to se when distance is small enough to stop motion.